# How to create a new array of objects for each String Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, data-structures

**Resume:**
For each value selected in a multi-select field, a function is called and add the value to a string. All I want is to add it as a Object into a array. Example:

**1 options selected:**

```
Current:
"selected01"
Desired: 
[ { "value": "selected01"} ]
```

**2 options selected:**

```
Current: 
"selected01, selected02"
Desired:
[ {"value": "selected01"}, {"value":"selected02"}]
```

**Full explanation:**

I have a function, that receives a String and add it to the state the value. Example:

```
handleSelectChange (value) {
    this.setState({ value })
}
```

So imagine you have a multi selectable field with three choices and select two of them.

It will call:

```
onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
```

The state will be then:

```
state.value: 'selected01, selected02'
```

In case you select one more:

```
state.value: 'selected01, selected02, selected03'
```

***But*** what I'm trying to do is to have a Array with 3 objects:

```
Object: 
[
  {"value": "select01"},
  {"value": "select02"},
  {"value": "select03"}
]
```

Another way to see the desired output (console.log):

```
state: [3]
  [0]: Object
  [1]: Object
  [2]: Object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this.setState(value.split(", "));

Comment: maybe I'm not getting the question but won't a simple value.split(',') do the trick?

Comment: if you want to convert that string into array of object, what will be the key?? if you want to convert into array of strings then use `split(',')`, you will get `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: I don't see how the split will get my value and create an Object with the value. The selected field are being added to a String, and I need it to have added to a new Object.
Current with one option: "selected01"
Desired:                          [ { "selected01"} ]

Comment: @LucasOliveiraSilva that object should have the key, what will be the key that you want it will be `[{key: 'selected01'}, {key: 'selected02'}]`.

Comment: Your desired result has an invalid structure as objects within the array don't have a key, you would rather have `[
  'select01',
  'select02',
  'select03'
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

```
handleSelectChange (value) {
  this.setState({value})
  let valuesArr = value.split(',')
  let valuesArrObj = []
  valuesArr.forEach((val) => {
    valuesArrObj.push({
      [val]: val
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this.getState() add your selection and then do a this.setState(). For example (using lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#concat):

```
this.setState(_.concat(this.getState(), { value }))
```

Comment: There are many ways. I only provided one possible example solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.setState()` for insert element, and `this.getState()` for get element

for any info go [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: This is not related to my question.